# Getting weird results when image traced using line art

Tags: adobe-illustrator, line-art, image-trace

I tried to make a **monoline text** effect from a text by `rasterizing` it first and then `image tracing` using `line art` preset. But I am getting weird results as shown in the images. How can I fix this issue to get a clean line art of the text ?

[image: Rasterizing]

`Object` > `Rasterize`

[image: Line art preset]

Selected `Line Art` from drop down.

[image: Image trace settings]

Image trace `settings`.

[image: GPU preview and Outline view of result]

Results.

[image]
This is what I want to achieve.

Comment: why are you using image trace on a vector text? why not use a different vector effect/tool instead?

Comment: Dont trace use offset. Note that outline fonts may not be possible to convert into single line fonts cleanly as there is no guarantee the stems will meet sanely. typically the letter K fails. Also tge trace does not understand the thinning effect. Anyway your stroke is set too wide.

Comment: @Luciano I wasn't to apply some brush stroke effects on my text for a poster. For that the text has to be monoline. Otherwise the brush effect will get applied to the outline as a stroke, which is not desired. I found this method to convert normal text to monoline here in an another question.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Try using a light or thin variant of a sans serif font, not a bold font.

Comment: This is an interesting question. With the amount of care and detail that is required to create well formed glyphs, it might be hard to get around drawing the letters by hand. Also note, that in order to make a font look "monoline", you will have to adjust the thickness of the vertical and horizontal strokes differently.

Comment: There are single line fonts like https://github.com/cmiscm/leonsans which might better suit your needs. Not usable directly in AI though. Conversion workflow might require some more googling on the topic. Or look for plotter fonts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing around with the `Rasterize Settings` dialog box I found a solution. It was the `Resoulution` which made the problem. You have to pick **Use Document Raster Effects Resolution** from the drop down to get required `Line art` effect. I set it to **High (300 ppi)**, which ended up in weird results.

[image]